# postgresql hierarchy table based on two column

Tags: sql, postgresql, hierarchy, hierarchical

I need to make sure we have support to create a hierarchy table based on a "father/son" table.
Example:

| F | S |
| --- | --- |
| a | b |
| b | c |
| b | d |
| b | e |
| e | f |
| e | g |
| b | m |
| z | n |
| m | k |

Expected result:

| L | L1 | L2 | L3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | c |  |
| a | b | d |  |
| a | b | e |  |
| e | f |  |  |
| e | g |  |  |
| a | b | m | k |
| z | n |  |  |

Any idea, suggestion?

Thank you

Comment: Left join the same table 3 times with child = parent? Are the levels fixed?

Comment: a recursive cte will do it, so that  is an idea for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with 
recursive cte(id, path) as
(
select f, f::text from   t where  f not in(select s from t where s is not null)
union all
select t.s, cte.path || '/' || t.s from cte join t on cte.id = t.f 
)

select  id      
       ,path[1] as root
       ,path[2] as l1
       ,path[3] as l2
       ,path[4] as l3
       ,path[5] as l4
from 
(
select  id 
       ,regexp_split_to_array(path, '/') as path
from    cte
) cte
```

| id | root | l1 | l2 | l3 | l4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | a | null | null | null | null |
| z | z | null | null | null | null |
| b | a | b | null | null | null |
| n | z | n | null | null | null |
| m | a | b | m | null | null |
| e | a | b | e | null | null |
| d | a | b | d | null | null |
| c | a | b | c | null | null |
| k | a | b | m | k | null |
| g | a | b | e | g | null |
| f | a | b | e | f | null |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/13hPfmLf)

Comment: you're welcome. please choose the answer and vote up.

Answer (score 2):

First three levels:

```
SELECT L0.F AS L, L1.F AS L1, L2.F AS L2, L3.S AS L3
FROM t L0
LEFT JOIN t L1
ON L0.S = L1.F
LEFT JOIN t L2
ON L1.S = L2.F
LEFT JOIN t L3
ON L2.S = L3.S
LEFT JOIN t nonexistent
ON L0.F = nonexistent.S
WHERE nonexistent.S IS NULL
```

Explanation:

- dimension1 is L0
- dimension2 is L1
- dimention3 is L2
- we ensure that L0 has no father by keeping only the L0 records that have no father

Maybe you need to change somewhat the logic, please let me know if I misunderstood the exact intention.

In more general terms, if you need n levels, then you will need to generate code. In PHP You can do it like this:

```
$SELECT = "SELECT L0.F AS L";
$FROM = "t L0";
for ($index = 1; $index < $n; $index++) {
    $SELECT .= ", L{$index}.F AS L{$index}";
    $FROM .= " LEFT JOIN L" . $index . " ON L" . ($index - 1) . ".S = L" . $index . "F";
}
$FROM .= " LEFT JOIN t nonexistent ON L0.F = nonexistent.S ";
WHERE = "WHERE nonexistent.S IS NULL";
$query = "{$SELECT} ${FROM} {$WHERE}";
```

Of course, you can use the language you prefer to generate such an n-dimensional select, if PHP is not a technology you use, then kindly consider the above as a pseudo-code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer.

I can only query the table with sql language and i don't know the max number of levels i have in the table.

Thanks

Comment: this is posted as an answer and not a comment

Comment: You can generate the query for 100 levels, for example and find the record with the highest number of columns. That number will be the number of levels you need.